# How to run action while ensuring job runs every time regardless of needs skipped?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to deploy a pull request to an Azure Web App using GitHub Actions. I have four jobs: pre-build, build, deploy and deploy-update. The pre-build job creates an Azure resource, the build job builds the application, deploys job deploy the application for frist time when pr is opened and the deploy-update job updates the deployed application.

The problem is that when the pull request is updated, the pre-build job is skipped, but the build job still runs. I want the deploy-update job to run only when the build job is successful and the pull request is updated. However, the deploy-update job is getting skipped because the pre-build job is not running.

How can I ensure that the deploy-update job runs only when the build job is successful and the pull request is updated, even if the pre-build job is skipped?

GitHub action :

```
jobs:
  pre-build:
    if: (github.event.action == 'opened' || github.event.action == 'reopened') && github.event.action != 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Pre-Build Checks
    steps:
      # Azure resource creation steps here

  build:
    if: always() && github.event.action != 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: pre-build
    name: Build Job
    steps:
      # Build steps here

  deploy:
    if: (github.event.action == 'opened' || github.event.action == 'reopened') && github.event.action != 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    name: Deploy Job
    steps:
      # Deploy steps here

  deploy-update:
    if: (github.event.action == 'synchronize')  && github.event.action != 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    name: Deploy Update Job
    steps:
      # Deploy-update steps here
```

Any suggestion?